# Mui Input - Full width broken with min & max attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've put together a sandbox because I could not believe it was really happening but here it is:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-swanson-yxj4n2?file=/NumberField.js:1075-1097

The issue is simply, if you have `min` & `max` attributes set on the html input, the width is reduced. This is not represented in any css either. If you have either one of the `min` or `max` then the width is correctly applied.

With `max`

[image]

without max

[image]

Is it possible to get it full width with MUI and still have `min` & `max` attirbutes?

Comment: Interesting ... I wanted to comment on this, but that became large enough for an answer. Sorry that I'm guessing a bit there. I learned something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This apparently happens in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

It seems to be not caused by MUI, but a simple HTML file shows this behavior already:

```
<html><body>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="1000" />
</body></html>
```

Also setting or not setting `min` has a similar effect.

### Conclusion

It seems to me that the field tries to be large enough to fit the largest possible
number defined by `min`/`max`. If `min` or `max` is not defined, the field
is rendered with some default "probably large enough" size.

*(I'm guessing here, I'm sorry, I couldn't find it documented.)*

After all, I think there is no objectively "correct" width of an input element, if no styles
are specified, so I think it's fair enough for the browsers to expect the
developer to specify it, if desired.

### Applying custom styles

In MUI you can set `fullWidth` property of the `TextField` component:

```
<MUITextField
    fullWidth
    ...
/>
```

Of course, you can set some styles specifically, with `style={ ... }` or `classes={ ... }`:

```
<MUITextField
    classes={{
        root: 'myTextFieldClass',
    }}
    style={{
        width: '100%',
    }}
    ...
/>
```